# XLST Transform only specific tag value nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I want to transform XML, but will choose only specific records with given value. How can i do that?

Here is the sample XML. I only want to get the records which have CURRENCY value equals to USD. I want to eliminate products with TL currency.

```
<PRODUCTS>
 <PRODUCT ID="9563">
   <CODE><![CDATA[72127]]></CODE>
   <NAME><![CDATA[SAMPLE PRODUCT NAME]]></NAME>
   <PRICE><![CDATA[57.90]]></PRICE>
   <PRICE_DISCOUNT><![CDATA[48.50]]></PRICE_DISCOUNT>
   <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
 </PRODUCT>
 <PRODUCT ID="9564">
   <CODE><![CDATA[72128]]></CODE>
   <NAME><![CDATA[SAMPLE ANOTHER PRODUCT NAME ]]></NAME>
   <PRICE><![CDATA[67.90]]></PRICE>
   <PRICE_DISCOUNT><![CDATA[58.50]]></PRICE_DISCOUNT>
   <CURRENCY>TL</CURRENCY>
 </PRODUCT>
<PRODUCTS>
```

Comment: Learn about predicates?  http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about the problem the other way around - start with an *identity transformation* (that copies the input to the output unchanged, you can find hundreds of examples of this in other questions) and then override it to ignore the elements you *don't* want to keep

```
<xsl:template match="PRODUCT[not(CURRENCY = 'USD')]" />
```